# How to remove popup window showing function definition in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm writing the body of a function in VSCode, a window pops up showing the definition of the function, as shown in the attached screenshot. Does anyone know if there's a setting I can use to remove this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Not a duplicate, the other one is about hover tooltips, this is about tooltips that pop up "when I'm writing the body of a function". Neither is named super well, but solutions are different.

Answer (score 31):

That window is the signature help / parameter hints. Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to cancel out of an individual popup, or set`"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false` to disable it entirely.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your quick reply. I'm using the UI to edit settings, and when I set Editor > Parameter Hints: Enabled to false, it gets automatically toggled back to 'true' when I exit or click elsewhere on the screen. Could you tell me how to find the actual settings.json file that has this setting in it? I haven't been able to find it yet.

Comment: With the settings editor open, click on the `{}` symbol at the right of the tab bar to open the raw `settings.json` file. Settings getting reverted unexpectedly could also be caused by an extension so you may need try to disable extensions if you are still seeing weird behavior

Comment: Using Matt's suggestion works on 1.61.0, and also has the benefit that if you _do_ wish to see the function definition/description, you can hover over the function name (i.e. just left of the parenthesis your cursor is within).

Answer (score 9):

You should try setting `"editor.quickSuggestions": false` and `"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false` to disable the suggestions.

Comment: Right now I have 
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": false,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    },
and "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
No luck though.

Answer (score 4):

Parameter hints could be useful, I would suggest to set simple keybindings to toggle between show/hide parameter hints.

I use the following settings/keybindings to toggle using `shift+space` and `space`.

- Disable parameter hint by adding `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false` to `settings.json`.
- Bind `shift+space` to trigger parameter hints. Default is `ctrl+shift+space`.

```
//keybindings.json
    { 
        "key": "shift+space",
        "command": "editor.action.triggerParameterHints",
        "when": "editorHasSignatureHelpProvider && editorTextFocus" 
    },
```

- Bind `space` to hide parameter hint.Default is `esc`.

```
//keybindings.json
    {
        "key": "space",
        "command": "closeParameterHints",
        "when": "editorFocus && parameterHintsVisible" 
    }
```