# How to go straight to the definition without the dialog in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I try to go to certain definition I am getting always this annoying dialog
[image]

How can it be removed, and I will be navigated strait to the required definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

The solution was to check "goto" in Multiple Definitions instead of peek

Answer (score 0):

Check if this answer helps you toggle off the feature [How to remove popup window showing function definition in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444047/how-to-remove-popup-window-showing-function-definition-in-vscode)

It seems that you can't go directly to the definition, but the shortcut is already defined.

[image]

Comment: I am talking about this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82899