# In Visual Studio Code, why the option "editor.parameterHints.enable" has no effect on the pop-up hint?

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, ide

I want to disable the capability of Visual Studio Code to display code definition, without affecting hover compiler messages.

According to this post: [How to remove popup window showing function definition in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444047/how-to-remove-popup-window-showing-function-definition-in-vscode) I should disable "editor.parameterHints.enabled".

But after disabling it, the definition is still showing:

[image]

How do I disable it properly?

Comment: What version of VSCode are you using?

Comment: Which compiler, babel, TS, Rust, ect... ?

Comment: The version is 1.58.0-insider (the latest when I wrote this). The compiler is scala-2.13 and metal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metals contributor here .
The feature you're seeing is generically caled `hover` and it's the result of Metals implementing the `textDocument/hover` request as specified by LSP.

Some editors, like VSCode, trigger that request when the mouse hovers on a piece of text, and - if the server responds - they show a popup with the content of the response.

You can control this behavior in VSCode by using the `editor.hover.enabled` setting.

For example, if you set it to `false` then you won't get popups on hover anymore, and you will need to manually trigger them. The default keybinding for this should be `CTRL K CTRL I` (i.e. keep CTRL pressed and hit K followed by I).

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I only want to hide display of function definition in the code "first section of the pop-up", this setting `editor.hover.enabled` will hide both this and the compiler info/warning

Comment: Looks like this feature is pending for 3 straight years with very little progress (though several circumvention are proposed). So I'm just going to accept it:

https://github.com/microsoft/language-server-protocol/issues/377

Answer (score 1):

It seems that bloop is responsible for this popup, it doesn't look like a function parameter popup. That means that there might be another setting besides “editor.parameterHints.enable” in one of your scala related extensions.

For example Scala (Metals) extension offers a hover, but there isn't a setting to turn it off, as far as I can tell:

[image]

Comment: you are right, the setting is missing from plugin, will submit a feature request ASAP

Comment: As https://github.com/scalameta/metals-feature-requests/issues/209, will accept the answer in 2 days