# Visual Studio Code How to get rid of popup?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When working in visual studio code I often get popups that looks like this [image]

I can't seam to get rid of them without grabbing the mouse and clicking off somewhere. Sometimes I do find these useful, but 9.9/10 times they're just annoying and slow down my coding process. I'm just wondering if there's a short cut to close them. Or even if I can default them to not show and have a short cut that shows it on the selected component just incase I need it.

If not I'd rather them just not be there, is there a good way to just get rid of them all together. these things have taken way more of my time than they saved by a long shot.

Sometimes, a similar popup shows up that has arrows at the bottom and I loose the ability to move around with the up and down arrows. These ones are a lot less common but way more annoying.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444047/how-to-remove-popup-window-showing-function-definition-in-vscode

Comment: @flotho Oh, nice, that answers my question. I haven't really asked much questions here, How do I close this question? Or should I just delete it?

Comment: I just closed it as a duplicate since you indicated it was.