# message that pops up while writing python code on vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am not sure what it is actually called. I am a beginner. I am learning python and using VS Code as my code editor. But when I write codes the message in the red circle highlighted in the screenshot pops up. It's kind of annoying.

Can someone please help me with it? I don't know what it is called and would like to turn it off.

[image]

Comment: It can show a syntax, How you can use valid parameters in this built-in function

Answer (score 1):

That pop up just shows the structure of the function you are using. It includes parameter hints.

In the image it is showing the structure of print function. It's a useful feature to be honest.

Press esc to cancel out of an individual popup, or set"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false to disable it entirely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61928547/18381422
You can see this if you wanna know...how can it be made into useful feature from an annoying pop up.

Comment: why comment your answer when you can edit it

Comment: @rioV8 Mm... I just started answering and didn't notice the edit function. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

So, that box you have there is the documentation of the method you are calling. In this case, `print()`. It's actually quite useful. It'll give you a quick description of the parameters that you can pass into the function. For more confusing functions, the auto-documentation is a must have. But, of course, it is up to you.

You can disable it by setting "editor.parameterHints.enabled" to false in your .json

Answer (score 1):

This is a function provided by VS Code to display information such as method parameters. You can turn it off in settings.

Click the gear icon in the lower left corner and select **Settings**,

[image]

then search for **parameterhints**, and uncheck the options in the picture.

[image]

In addition, as mentioned above, you can also add the following configuration to the `settings.json` file to achieve the same effect.

```json
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
```