# How can i remove this on vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image]

I don't know if it's an extension or on settings

Comment: press Escape, disabling this will bite you later when you want the function arguments, for standard functions it might be overkill

Comment: Hey, have you seen these possible solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444047/how-to-remove-popup-window-showing-function-definition-in-vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- open VS code
- Press `ctrl + ,` it will take you to settings
- On the top nav bar click on `workspace`.
- On the left side of the panel click on `Text Editor` it will open a drop-down.
- then click on `Suggestions` and play with settings according to your taste.

[image: SS]

`!To turn off the suggestion set the delay to a max value of 9999 and aslo you cloud also turn off by going to quick suggestion section.`

Answer (score 0):

You can open settings menu or hit CTRL+, together, then you can search 'suggestion'.
There will be plenty of settings suggestion, you can choose what u want to be disabled as u want

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check and disable this extension. I think that is the root cause as your description
[image]

Comment: I don't have this extension, i think the comment come from vscode settings